# SCSS files not grouped in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

In the solution explorer, scss files usually have their .css, .css.map, .min.css files grouped together in a tree under the .scss file. However, my solution explorer is showing them all individually, which is causing some disorganization.

Can anyone help me out and let me know a shortcut/trick to get these files grouped together again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either manually edit the project file or make use of this nifty Visual Studio Extension:

[image]

The manual trick is to edit the project file and add the `DependentUpon` metadata to each file you want to show nested:

```
<ItemGroup>

    <!-- This will cause Visual Studio to show the file under Foo.1.cs -->
    <Compile Include="Foo.1.1.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Foo.1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>

    <!-- This will cause Visual Studio to show the file under Foo.cs -->
    <Compile Include="Foo.1.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Foo.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Foo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Source:

- [File Nesting Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ebde8fb-26d8-4374-a0eb-1e4e2665070c)